# Failed to execute stored procedure having full database level privileges

Tags: stored-procedures, mariadb

I am using MariaDB 10.0.20.

I do have one database e.g. "Db1", and have one stored procedure under this database named as "SP1". I created one user "user1" as:
GRANT ALL ON DB1.* to user1@'%' identified by '';

Now the problem is that, using this user I am not able to execute Stored procedure and it is returning below error:
ERROR 1370 (42000): execute command denied to user

I've execute the GRANT EXECUTE on user1 as well, but still no luck. 
The Security_type of procedure was set to "DEFINER", and later changing to "INVOKER" it didn't help.

Is there any issue with the Grants or SP ? Or its some bug with MariaDB?

Answer (score 0):

Got resolution :).
EXECUTE GRANT For stored Procedure is something like :
GRANT EXECUTE ON Procedure DB1.SP1 to user1;